# Using C-c C-f C-<x> in AucTeX randomly inserts font commands in old TeX style ({\sc xxx}) or modern one (\tesxtsc{xxx})

Tags: emacs, tex, auctex

I'm using AucTeX for years now...

I'm using emacs "26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.11)" and AucTeX 12.2.0 (installed from MELPA) on XUbuntu 19.10.

According to doc[1] (and years of usage...), hitting `C-c C-f C-<x>` should insert (`\text<xx>{yyy}`). e.g. `\textsc{yyy}`

However, on my machine, AucTeX randomly inserts font commands in old TeX style (`{\xx yyy}`) or modern one (`\text<xx>{yyy}`).

I have absolutely no clue why the behaviour is not consistent accross all .tex files, nor why it does not respect the documentation (always using modern syntax)....

PLEASE HELP!!!! This randomness is REALLY getting on my nerves!!! How can I get back a consistent behaviour???

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Font-Specifiers.html

Comment: Apparently using M-x latex-mode works around the problem... But why is it necessary in some buffer and not others?

Comment: Sounds like a different major mode is getting loaded for some reason.  For buffers that are behaving differently, compare the major mode (`M-: major-mode`) and the keybindings (`C-h k C-c C-f C-<x>`), that should give clues to what's going wrong.